# Discussions and email notifications on TFS tasks

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

We're new to TFS and have some tasks set up in Team Explorer. It seems the History pane is the right/best place to add notes/discussions (although it's very different from other tools I'm used to like bugzilla, jira, redmine)?

But how can we set it up so interested parties get notified of new comments on a task, preferably by email? We're all making it up as we go along with no prior TFS experience but I'd hope my experience with other tools (the project hasn't used a proper issue tracker before) would help me figure things out but it all seems rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the TFS 2010 Power Tools (this is removed for 2012 as it's setup in the web interface according to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/09/15/tfs-2012-power-tools-are-now-available.aspx) although I've not played with this in 2012), under **Team > Alerts Explorer** you can add alerts for email notifications.

It's pretty simple, you can get alerts for when work items are modified, created under a certain path, assigned to you etc, they are basically configured in a similar way to the work item queries so it's quite easy to setup what you want.

They can be setup by any users, so you might want to let your users setup their own custom rules as they like, then you logon as a generic user (such as your admin user) to setup team specific queries, or else you might end up with users complaining about getting emails no longer relevent to them or need changing, when the user that set them up leaves/moves etc...  Else you'll be hunting round to find who setup the original rules.